# CSS? How is this arrow made?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

This is driving me insane. I've been using the Firefox inspector to try to figure out how this arrow was made (below) on the [Headway site](http://headwaythemes.com/).

[image]

I've whittled away the code by deleting chunks via the inspector, and got it down to this:

[image]

No matter where I inspect, I can *not* find any such shape. No background image, no glyphs, nothing. It hardly even matters at this point, but I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out how they did this!

Any CSS gurus care to take a look and chime in? For the sake of learning. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a rotated square in the form of a [`::before` pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

As you can see, the element is a square (same `height`/`width`). The element is absolutely positioned with `left: 50%` and a negative `margin-left` of `-31px` (half the width) for horizontal centering. Finally, `transform: rotate(-45deg)` is used to rotate the square.

Here is the styling used:

```
.home-testimonial-wrapper:before
.home-cta-area::before, {
    display: block;
    width: 62px;
    height: 62px;
    background: #253031;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -31px;
    z-index: 5;
    content: "";
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Aside from this, if you're interested in seeing how to make a triangle using CSS, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work).

Comment: Something must be wrong with the Firefox inspector. No matter what I click on, I never see that CSS pop up on the right hand side.

Comment: Stuff like that (45-degree cuts) is usually done using transparent borders.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack For what it's worth, [this is what I get in Firefox](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AAKgZ.png).

Comment: @Shomz The question was **How is *this* arrow made?** I linked to [the canonical CSS triangle question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work), though.

Comment: Agreed, just saying. Gave you an upvote. Nope, wasn't my downvote.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Interesting! I can't click on `::before` in the code pane in the inspector, I *have* to click on it on the horizontal bar: http://i.imgur.com/HSG6hbk.png. Otherwise I won't get the CSS rule on the right. I'm gonna report that as a bug in FF. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: `::before` and after `::after` pseudo elements aren't technically part of the DOM. For a quite a while, no browser showed them when inspecting elements. I remember the day they started showing up in the elements pane on chrome canary. It was a good day.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a triangle by playing with borders of a zero width/height div:

```css
.triangleDiv {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0 100px 100px 100px;
        border-color: transparent transparent #000000 transparent;
    }
```

```html
<div class="triangleDiv"></div>
```

Just adjust the border-widths to get the size you want.  No need for transforms.  By adjusting which borders have width, you can 'rotate' the triangle.

Comment: Nice one, hope you don't mind me adding it as a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are good!

Just wanted to add, for design elements like that I always use one of two things.

1. Pseudo element to create the design feature ( as described above )
2. Pseudo element containing the design feature as an svg

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do what they've done with rotating the square, but a more common solution is to use the border property:

```
.example {
  position: relative;
}
.example:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; /* or wherever */
  left: 0; /* or wherever */
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
}
```